# Unused Varying Variables in Fragment Shader GLSL - Can they hurt Perf

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, gpu

What happens to the unused varying variables in GLSL
GPU's have inter shader buffers which would get populated with these values but since fragment shader is not using it , Wouldnt that be unnesscary computation which was being done in vertex shader (per vertex) & then dropped since it's not used in fragment shader.

1. Can GLSL compilers optimize these kind of wrong practices ?
2. If NOT , Would there be any performance improvement if these varying can   completely be removed from vertex shader from below exapmle ?

Note : I havent written this shader - I have come across this shader while profiling & debugging an GL app , So was curious to know if these could be causing any perf. issues or compiler would have optimized it - If not used in FS.

Example:

Vertex Shader

```
attribute vec3 Normal;
attribute vec4 Vertex;
uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
precision mediump float;
**varying vec3 N;**
**varying vec3 v;**
varying vec2 texCor;
void main(void)
{
    v = vec3(ModelViewMatrix * Vertex);
    N = normalize(NormalMatrix * Normal);
    gl_Position = ModelViewProjectionMatrix * Vertex;
    texCor = MultiTexCoord0.xy;
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D data;
**varying vec3 N;**
**varying vec3 v;**
varying vec2 texCor;
void main (void)
{
    vec2 TexCoord = texCor;
    vec4 RGB      = texture2D( data, TexCoord );
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0 , RGB.r);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Can GLSL compilers optimize these kind of wrong practices ?

In principle yes, although there is no guarantee they do as it requires state which is only available a link-time, not at shader compile time. It will be easier in Vulkan when all shaders in the pipeline are compiled at the same time.

> If NOT , Would there be any performance improvement if these varying can completely be removed from vertex shader

Quite probably yes, but YMMV. Don't tell the GPU to do something that you don't actually need it to do, that's just common sense ...

The main optimization here which is critical is actually data side. Most applications will interleave vertex data for all attributes, so if you have unused data elements in your interleaved buffers then that will get pulled into the GPU, wasting bandwidth, cache space, burning power, etc. It is highly unlikely that the graphics drivers can remove this inefficiency because the application can call `glMapBuffer` at any time.

In summary - optimize your shaders and your data structures to remove stuff you don't need. Also upload things at the correct precision (don't upload fp32 data if the shader only needs fp16, etc).

Comment: Thanks for explanation , I didnt quite understand what do you mean by "Do your uniform on uniform computations on the CPU in the application .." - I thought offloading this work to gpu (cores) would be faster than doing this on cpu ?, Or i am missing something here.

Comment: Actually I probably owe you an apology on that one; I read it quickly and read it as separate multiplications of MVP. You are obviously concatenating MVP on the CPU already - sorry! (Downside of answering quickly over lunch with a sandwich in one hand)

Answer (score 0):

You are using ancient syntax here that pre-dates GL's ability to separate shader stages.

The only way you are going to get this GLSL program up and running is if it is fully linked. At which point, an optimizing GLSL compiler (all of them?) is going to eliminate unlinked inputs/outputs (that is something that doesn't contribute to an output in the final stage).

This is all static analysis stuff that any GLSL implementation should be expected to know how to do considering active uniform determination is a mandatory part of the compile/link process. There is a rudimentary level of dead code elimination already guaranteed by the spec. for even the simplest of implementations.

Comment: As a specific example, NVIDIA's GLSL compiler is well-known for being a two-pass process. The initial compile is very fast because it's more or less syntax validation. Code generation comes at link-time, after all the other stages have been trimmed.

Comment: you meant to say on latest generation of GLSL compilers - These kind of optimizations will be built -in ?

Comment: Never assume "will" for optimizations - you're placing your application's performance in the hands of something you don't have control over. On mobile devices in particular there is a trade off between all of the optimizations and compile time which is often difficult. The only guarantee of "will optimize" can come from the application.

Comment: ... and as per my original answer; the biggest cost of unused things (vertex attributes) can't easily be optimized away. Even if the compiler optimizes out the varying between shaders, it's still sitting in your input stream wasting bandwidth.